# how to change nesting structure in XML using XSLT?

Tags: xml, nested, xslt-1.0

I'm a complete XSLT new beginner but I need to use it for a project I'm working on.

I have an XML file thant looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<table>
   <CLASS>
      <Name></Name>
      <Sex></Sex>
      <Age></Age>
      <Height></Height>
      <Weight></Weight>
   </CLASS>
</table>
```

and my desired output should look like this

```
<table>
   <CLASS>
      <Name> 
     <Sex>
          <Age>
              <Height>              
            <Weight>
            </Weight>
          </Height>
         </Age>
        </Sex>
      </Name>
   </CLASS>
</table>
```

I have now spent 2 days but I'm not able to fine a solution for that. I tried using for-each and read about grouping but unsure how to perform such change in nesting structure. I'm using XSLT 1.

Comment: Please explain the required logic for the transformation: what determines which element goes into which? Is it just the order in which they appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look as a task suitable for "a complete XSLT noob".

Assuming that each element under `CLASS` is supposed to be nested inside its immediately preceding sibling, you could adapt a method known as "sibling recursion":

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/table">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CLASS">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="CLASS/*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1]"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thank you, it works! This is rather meant to be an example of a bigger document with a structure similar to this one in the example that needs to be transformed into another structure with nesting on various levels (not only immediately preceding siblings). 
What is the best way to address the tags using the tags names?  For example if I would like to have a structure like this:
<table>
   <CLASS>
      <Name></Name>
      <Age><Height></Height>
      <Weight></Weight></Age>
      
   </CLASS>
</table>

Comment: There are no "tags" in XSLT. To address an *element* by its name, you use its name. I suggest you post a new question and clarify the requirement. Code on comments is difficult to read.